# Use resolve with es6 class syntax

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I want to use resolve to check if user is present on localStorage before controller fires up but can't get it to work.
Example:

```
//loginDirective.js

import {LoginController as controller} from './login.controller';
import template from './login.html';

export const loginDirective = () =>{
return{
    controller,
    template,
    scope:{},
    controllerAs:'vm',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E'
    }
}

//login.js
import {loginDirective} from './login.directive';
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

 export const login = angular.module('admin', [uiRouter])
.config(($stateProvider) => {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url     : '/login',
        template: '<login></login>',
        resolve : {
            loggedUser: function () {
                if(localStorage.getItem('user')){
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    })
})
.directive('login', loginDirective);

//LoginController

'use strict';

class LoginController {

constructor($state, AuthenticationService, loggedUser) {
    this.$state                = $state;
    this.AuthenticationService = AuthenticationService;
    this.email                 = '';
    this.password              = '';
    this.loggedIn              =  loggedUser;
}

login = () => {
    this.AuthenticationService.Login(this.email, this.password).then((result)                 => {
        this.loggedIn = result;
        if (this.loggedIn === true) {
            this.$state.go('home', {}, {reload: true});
        }
    });
    }

logout = () => {
    this.AuthenticationService.Logout();
    this.loggedIn = false;
    this.$state.go('login', {location: true});
}

}

LoginController.$inject = ['$state', 'AuthenticationService', 'loggedUser'];

export {LoginController}
```

This throws `Unknown provider: loggedUserProvider <- loggedUser`

Note:
I am using webpack, gulp and babel to transpile. WebPack has babel stage 1 enabled. 
I can see the resolve method in this.$state but that is not the way I want to access it.

Comment: Your 'login' state definition has no controller. So ui-router doesn't instantiate the login controller. So it can't pass anything to its constructor.

Comment: Login directive is responsible for handling that page and it has controller defined. Whole thing works except the resolve method

Comment: Yes, that's my point: since it's not the router which instantiates your controller, it can't pass the resolved loggedUser to the controller. The controller is not the controller of the state. It's the controller of a directive that happens to be used in the template of the state. So that can't work. Read https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component to understand how you must do: either use a controller and a template, or use a component.

Comment: you are right! I refactored all to use component so my resolve var gets injected in scope. if you care to post answer Ill be glad to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'login' state definition has no controller. So ui-router doesn't instantiate the login controller. So it can't pass anything to its constructor.

The controller is not the controller of the state. It's the controller of a directive that happens to be used in the template of the state. So that can't work.

Read https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component to understand how you must do: either use a controller and a template, or use a component.

Comment: The component approach actually didn't work for me, could be the ui-router version or something so I switched to using just controller and template

Comment: Note: It was the ui-router version after all